# Error ngFor en un servicio

Tags: angular

soy nuevo en esto de angular y estoy tratando de usar un servicio un un template con el ngFor pero me sale este error: `Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'`. adjunto el codigo

componente.html

```
<h1>Heroes <small>Marvel y DC</small></h1>
<hr>

<div class="card-columns">
  <div *ngFor="let heroe of heroes" class="card">
    <img class=" card-img-top" src="assets/img/aquaman.png" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block">Ver mas.</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

componente.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HeroesService, Heroe } from '../../services/heroes.service'; // importamos el servicio q 
queremos q se utilice en este componente y lo ponemos en el costructor

@Component({
  selector: 'app-heroes',
  templateUrl: './heroes.component.html',
})
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {
  heroes: Heroe[] = [];
  constructor(private _heroesService: HeroesService) {} 

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.heroes = this._heroesService.getHeroes(); 
    console.log(this.heroes);
  }
}
```

en esta parte me muestra el arreglo con todos los objetos normalmente

appModule

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

// rutas
import { FeatureRoutingModule } from './app.routes';

// servicios
import { HeroesService } from './services/heroes.service';
// componentes
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './components/shared/navbar/navbar.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, NavbarComponent, HomeComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, FeatureRoutingModule], 
  providers: [HeroesService], 
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]En la imagen adjunta les pongo el service.ts ya que no puedo poner mas codigo

es un arreglo de 7 objetos pero solo puse 1 para q no sea tan largo el código

Comment: por lo que tengo entendido no es una buena practica usar tus métodos del `service` directamente al `component.ts`, deberias llamar a esos metodos desde tus componentes, las variables con datos debes agregarlos al `component.ts`

Answer (score 1):

Resuelto, no habia importado el modulo HeroesComponent al AppModule ni tampoco el HttpClientModule, gracias por sus respuestas

Comment: Recuerda marcar tu respuesta como aceptada

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer `HeroesComponent` no es parte del `AppModule`,por lo que puedo inferir que este componente esta declarado en otro módulo, revise si este módulo que declara a `HeroesComponent` tiene importado el modulo de `CommonModule`

**CommonModule:** Es el módulo de angular que nos ofrece las directivas de `*ngFor, *ngIf`, etc

Answer (score 0):

falta importar el commonModule que tiene las directivas de *ngIf ,*ngFor en el modulo.